# putting Interstitial AD on Floating Action Button ist not working

Tags: java, android, admob, floating-action-button, interstitial

I tried to put the Interstitial Ad on my Floating Action Button, so I did following:

In the onCreate of my MainActivity I wrote:

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();

        mInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(MainActivity.this);
        mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId("My ID");
        mInterstitialAd.loadAd(adRequest);


        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                displayInterstitial();
                Snackbar.make(view, "Danke für deine Unterstützung <3", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });
```

And also I wrote this method in the MainActivity:

```
    public void displayInterstitial() {

        mInterstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAdLoaded() {
                super.onAdLoaded();
                if(mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()){
                    mInterstitialAd.show();
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onAdClosed() {
            }
        });
    }
}
```

What is wrong with this code and why does my Interstitial Ad not display if I click on the Floating Action Button?

Answer (score 0):

In your code Ad will be loaded before you create `AdListener` object.

You should set listener first in `onCreate()` method and call `mInterstitialAd.loadAd(adRequest)` after click on the button.

Change your code like this:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(MainActivity.this);
    mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId("My ID");
    mInterstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAdLoaded() {
            super.onAdLoaded();
            if(mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()){
                mInterstitialAd.show();
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onAdClosed() {
        }
    });

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            displayInterstitial();
            Snackbar.make(view, "Danke für deine Unterstützung <3", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });
}

 public void displayInterstitial() {
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    mInterstitialAd.loadAd(adRequest);
 }
```

After click just wait few seconds for ad to be loaded.

Comment: Is there a way to display the Interstitial ad without any delay in this case?

Comment: Yes, you can preload ad for example in `onCreate()` and then after click on the button just check if ad is already loaded and display it. Check this [link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admob/android/interstitial#add_interstitial_ads_to_an_activity) to see an example